# Selenium/Chrome - Selecting a Checkbox Input without an ID

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Thanks for the assistance in advance.
New to Selenium/Chrome and have had a good run of it until I hit  a specific scenario.

I have a modal the contains 5 fields (3 drop-downs and a UL with 2 LI)

Each LI contains a label and input-checkbox.

All of the drop-downs have an Id so they were easy to manipulate with `FindElement(By.Id("ID")).SelectText("TEXT");`

However the Li's within the Ul do not have them and I have gotten NoSuchElementExceptions with every attempt to locate them.

```html
<ul id="CertificatesToAdd" name="CertificatesToAdd" class="nav nav-list 
    checkbox-list add-certificate-required" data-trigger="manual" data- placement="top">
  <li>
    <label class="checkbox" style="font-weight:normal !important;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="add-certificate-checkbox" 
    value="171">
    Certificate of Registration
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="checkbox" style="font-weight:normal !important;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="add-certificate-checkbox" 
    value="172">
    Collection Agency License
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried both of the FindElement lines below the todo and both return
`OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element`

```js
new SelectElement(BaseTest.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("AddCertificateCountry")))
  .SelectByText("Canada");
new SelectElement(BaseTest.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("AddCertificateState")))
  .SelectByText("Alberta");

//TODO: correct input value for checkbox
new SelectElement(BaseTest.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(
  "#CertificateToAdd>li:nth-child(2)"))).SelectByValue("172");

new SelectElement(BaseTest.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(
  "//*[@id="CertificatesToAdd"]/li[2]/label/input"))).SelectByValue("172");
```

Any ideas would be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the *checkbox* associated with the `<label>` tags you can use the following solutions:

- *Certificate of Registration*:

  ```
  BaseTest.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[@class='checkbox'][normalize-space()='Certificate of Registration']/input[@class='add-certificate-checkbox']")).Click();
  ```
- *Collection Agency License*:

  ```
  BaseTest.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[@class='checkbox'][normalize-space()='Collection Agency License']/input[@class='add-certificate-checkbox']")).Click();
  ```

Comment: @WilliamHowell Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Here you're targeting the li:

```
new SelectElement(BaseTest.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(
  "#CertificateToAdd>li:nth-child(2)"))).SelectByValue("172");
```

Here your xpath means that input is a child of the label rather than a sibling:

```
new SelectElement(BaseTest.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(
  "//*[@id="CertificatesToAdd"]/li[2]/label/input"))).SelectByValue("172");
```

I think you can probably figure it out from there.

Comment: Thanks mate, it is all in the details.